# Duvida sobre cookies em variável e JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

É Possível criar uma variável em javascript ou jquery e armazenar um cookies nela por um determinado tempo X?

Comment: Você está se referindo a o uso de cookies?

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo Acho que seria o nome correto

Comment: Pode usar localstorage, depende muito o que você quer fazer..

Comment: Precisa explicar o melhor o que deseja. Em JS é possível, em jQuery não pode porque ele não é uma linguagem de programação e não possui variáveis. Mas não faz sentido guardar um *cookie*  em uma variável, ainda mais se quer cache. Pode guardar um valor em um *cookie*. Se for algo mais complexo aí precisa de *localstorage*, mas não sabemos o que precisa.

Comment: @Fbor Quero armazenar o ip + data pra somar tudo e criar tipo uma identificação por x minutos e usar em uma api

Comment: @Maniero Seria basicamente isso que você falou preciso criar um cookie armazenado por tempo X pra usar usar em algumas outras funções.

Comment: Usar cookie as vezes é ruim porque o cliente pode apagar ou bloquear quando quiser.

Comment: o IP do usuário e a data já são acessíveis no lado do servidor, não vejo a necessidade de armazenar o mesmo em um Cookie. quanto a controle de acesso, você não deve confiar em dados que possam ser editados no lado do client, então aconselho que utilize jwt com encryption, e armazene o mesmo no localStorage. desta forma, os dados sensiveis do usuario poderam fazer parte do token.

Comment: Recomendo usar outro tipo de identificação, esse teu modelo é bem falho, mas caso necessite usar isso mesmo, pode salvar no Localstorage com tuas tratativas.